# SQL Server Query - Sum of Event Time Between Events

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the sum of 'production' events between 'failure' events.  It is a bit difficult to explain, so lets look at the data as well as the desired result.  See below tables.  The input table is also given as text at the bottom.

The items in yellow are the failure events (code 100).  The items in green are the production events (code 200).  I need the production time between the failure events, as seen in the last table.  Note that the last failure event does not have any production events after it, thus it need to be ignored.

My guess is the Rank() function will be involved somewhere, but I'm struggling with this one!

[image: Event data]

[image: Result data]

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| StartDate           | EndDate             | DurationInHours | Equipment  | EventCode |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-01 06:31:51 | 2014-01-01 09:14:57 | 2.7183          | Equipment1 | 100       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-01 09:17:20 | 2014-01-01 13:34:40 | 4.2889          | Equipment1 | 200       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-01 21:59:49 | 2014-01-01 23:20:29 | 1.3444          | Equipment1 | 200       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-03 22:23:33 | 2014-01-03 22:41:57 | 0.3067          | Equipment1 | 100       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-03 22:51:49 | 2014-01-04 05:48:43 | 6.9483          | Equipment1 | 200       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-04 06:26:18 | 2014-01-04 14:04:20 | 7.6339          | Equipment1 | 200       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-04 14:32:44 | 2014-01-04 18:07:29 | 3.5792          | Equipment1 | 200       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-04 18:27:16 | 2014-01-04 22:40:37 | 4.2225          | Equipment1 | 200       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-04 22:40:37 | 2014-01-04 23:13:15 | 0.5439          | Equipment1 | 100       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-04 23:13:15 | 2014-01-04 23:13:20 | 0.0014          | Equipment1 | 200       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-04 23:13:26 | 2014-01-05 07:24:11 | 8.1792          | Equipment1 | 200       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-05 07:24:11 | 2014-01-05 09:24:45 | 2.0094          | Equipment1 | 100       |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please, don't post code, sample data as images, help us to help you, instead of images post it as text formatted.

Comment: I have created a text table at the bottom - sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach which I think will be more efficient. Instead of using APPLY with TOP(1) and ORDER BY this approach uses LEAD() OVER() then aggregates within those date boundaries.

See this alternative [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b7e0/5)

**Query 1**:

```
select 
      t1.Equipment
    , grp.StartDate
    , grp.EndDate
    , sum(t1.DurationInHours) sumDurationInHours
from table1 as t1
inner join (
    select
          t2.Equipment
        , t2.StartDate
        , lead(t2.EndDate) over(partition by t2.Equipment order by t2.EndDate) EndDate
    from table1 as t2
    where t2.eventcode = 100
   ) grp on t1.Equipment = grp.Equipment
        and t1.StartDate between grp.StartDate and grp.EndDate
where t1.eventcode = 200
group by
      t1.Equipment
    , grp.StartDate
    , grp.EndDate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b7e0/5/0)**:

```
|  Equipment |            StartDate |              EndDate | sumDurationInHours |
|------------|----------------------|----------------------|--------------------|
| Equipment1 | 2014-01-01T06:31:51Z | 2014-01-03T22:41:57Z |             5.6333 |
| Equipment1 | 2014-01-03T22:23:33Z | 2014-01-04T23:13:15Z |            22.3853 |
| Equipment1 | 2014-01-04T22:40:37Z | 2014-01-05T09:24:45Z |             8.1806 |
```

Comment: Thanks it is a LOT faster.  There is a small problem though.  In my data, it sometimes happens for two 100 events to appear in succession.  The code takes the time of the first  200 event after the successive 100 event.  What needs to happen is those successive 100 events need to be combined as one event

Comment: So, suggest you supply sample data that covers normal and all exception conditions. Also provide the "expected result". Please don't expect volunteers supply data; which you already have. Note include new data as text in the question

Comment: No problem, I'll figure that part out myself.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Glad this one was faster.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this 
I hope it fulfills your requirement.

```
Create table test(STARTDATE datetime, enddate datetime, eventcode int)

insert into test 
Select '2017-01-01 06:31:51',  '2017-01-01 09:14:51'  ,100 union all
Select '2017-01-01 10:31:51',  '2017-01-01 11:14:51'  ,200 union all
Select '2017-01-01 12:31:51',  '2017-01-01 15:15:51'  ,200 union all
Select '2017-01-01 17:21:51',  '2017-01-01 18:14:51'  ,100 union all
Select '2017-01-01 19:31:51',  '2017-01-01 19:51:51'  ,200 union all
Select '2017-01-01 20:11:51',  '2017-01-01 21:14:51'  ,100 union all
Select '2017-01-01 22:31:51',  '2017-01-01 23:14:51'  ,200 

with cte as
(
Select ROW_NUMBER() over( order by startdate) rn, * From test Where  
eventcode = 100 
)
Select a.STARTDATE as failuredate,
cast(datediff(mi,a.STARTDATE, b.STARTDATE)as varchar(10))  DiffInMinutes
from cte a
left join cte b    on a.rn+1 = b.rn
```

Just convert the DiffInMinutes into hh:mm.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Per my understanding you took the time difference between the 100 events.  That is not the requirement.  The 200 events in between the 100 events need to be summed as the duration

Answer (score 1):

You can use APPLY (more than once) where the aliases of one apply can be used in the next. Note this approach may not suit large tables.

see it working here at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8316e/3)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([StartDate] datetime, [EndDate] datetime, [DurationInHours] decimal(12,4), [Equipment] varchar(10), [EventCode] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([StartDate], [EndDate], [DurationInHours], [Equipment], [EventCode])
VALUES
    ('2014-01-01 06:31:51', '2014-01-01 09:14:57', 2.7183, 'Equipment1', 100),
    ('2014-01-01 09:17:20', '2014-01-01 13:34:40', 4.2889, 'Equipment1', 200),
    ('2014-01-01 21:59:49', '2014-01-01 23:20:29', 1.3444, 'Equipment1', 200),
    ('2014-01-03 22:23:33', '2014-01-03 22:41:57', 0.3067, 'Equipment1', 100),
    ('2014-01-03 22:51:49', '2014-01-04 05:48:43', 6.9483, 'Equipment1', 200),
    ('2014-01-04 06:26:18', '2014-01-04 14:04:20', 7.6339, 'Equipment1', 200),
    ('2014-01-04 14:32:44', '2014-01-04 18:07:29', 3.5792, 'Equipment1', 200),
    ('2014-01-04 18:27:16', '2014-01-04 22:40:37', 4.2225, 'Equipment1', 200),
    ('2014-01-04 22:40:37', '2014-01-04 23:13:15', 0.5439, 'Equipment1', 100),
    ('2014-01-04 23:13:15', '2014-01-04 23:13:20', 0.0014, 'Equipment1', 200),
    ('2014-01-04 23:13:26', '2014-01-05 07:24:11', 8.1792, 'Equipment1', 200),
    ('2014-01-05 07:24:11', '2014-01-05 09:24:45', 2.0094, 'Equipment1', 100)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
t1.startdate, ca1.nextend, ca2.sumDurationInHours
from table1 as t1
cross apply (
  select top(1) EndDate as nextend
  from table1 as t2
  where t2.StartDate > t1.StartDate and t2.EventCode = 100
  order by t2.StartDate 
  ) ca1
cross apply (
  select sum(DurationInHours) as sumDurationInHours
  from table1 as t3
  where t3.StartDate >= t1.StartDate 
  and t3.EndDate < ca1.nextend
  and t3.EventCode = 200
  ) ca2
where t1.eventcode = 100
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8316e/3/0)**:

```
|            startdate |              nextend | sumDurationInHours |
|----------------------|----------------------|--------------------|
| 2014-01-01T06:31:51Z | 2014-01-03T22:41:57Z |             5.6333 |
| 2014-01-03T22:23:33Z | 2014-01-04T23:13:15Z |            22.3839 |
| 2014-01-04T22:40:37Z | 2014-01-05T09:24:45Z |             8.1806 |
```

Comment: I tested this on my dataset consisting of thousands of items.  It is extremely slow (been running for 30 minutes now).  Is it supposed to be that slow?

Comment: Only an execution plan would reveal specific performance issues. Not possible for me to be definitive on the detail available to me.